# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects using redux/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, crud, mern, redux-toolkit

Hey guys I'm using redux/toolkit, How can I update the user, Although it updates and saves on the backend, I get an error of this?

I tried using direct put in onsubmit, it works but I feel uncomfortable since it will make the code messy.

> https://localhost/api/users/:id

this one works but I'd like to use redux and API calls

Submit button

```
const onSubmit =  async ({username, email, studentid}) => {
        let user = {username, email ,studentid}
        updateUser(id, user,dispatch) 
      }
```

Apicalls.js

```
export const updateUser = async (id,user, dispatch) =>{
  dispatch(updateStart())

  try {
    const res = await publicRequest.put(`/users/${id}`, user) 
    console.log(res.data)
    dispatch(updatenSuccess(res.data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(updatenFailure)
  }
}
```

AuthSlice.js

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState: {
        currentUser: null,
        isFetching : false,
        isError: false,
        isSuccess: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        updateStart: (state)=>{
            state.isFetching = true;
            state.isError = false;
        },
        updateSuccess: (state, action) =>{
            state.isFetching = true;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.currentUser = action.payload
        },
        updateFailure: (state) =>{
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.isError = true;
        }, 
    }

})

export const {rupdateStart, updatenSuccess, updatenFailure} = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer
```

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely just dispatching `undefined` here, due to a typo.

it should be `updateSuccess`, not `updatenSuccess`

also, `dispatch(updatenFailure)` should be `dispatch(updatenFailure())`

All that said, you are writing a lot of stuff by hand here that is already part of RTK - either in the form of `createAsyncThunk` or `RTK Query`. I would highly recommend you to go through the full [official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) and learning those concepts before writing more code.